# Dynamically retrieving result of stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a rest endpoint which looks like below. Now based on the ReportSource name I want to execute that stored procedure. There are 40 such stored procedures and I do not want to create the entity classes for each one of them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BAService.Dtos
{
    class BARequestDTO
    {
        public int ReportID { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AsOfDate { get; set; }
        public string ReportSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("BAReportRequest")]
public string BAReportRequest(BARequestDTO dto)
{
    try
    {
        var test = _bIReportRepositoryBA.RunReport(dto);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _LogService.Error(string.Format("Unable to save data dictionary"), ex);

    }
    return test;
}
```

The only way I know to execute the stored procedure is to call it like below. 
In this approach I will have to create 40 new entity object which can receive the result from database. I am lazy and I am looking for a general way of executing stored procedure and getting the result in json without creating entity object for each stored procedure.

```
public List<EmployerDashboardDetailsDto> RunReport(BIReportDto dto)
{
    return _DBContext.Database
                    .SqlQuery<usp_EmployerDashboardStatistics>("report.usp_Report1 @exchangeID", new SqlParameter("@exchangeID", dto.ID))
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you doing DB first? That would generate your entity classes for you wouldn't it? Creating 40 classes by hand is a lot of work, I agree. Are you trying to bypass the auto code generation by EF as well in search of something else?

Comment: I am using Code first from existing database. The idea is to decouple the code from the database. So if tomorrow I add a new stored procedure I should not need a code change to make it work. From that perspective I am looking for a more dynamic solution